# What is the equivalent to VBAs "&" in R?

Tags: r, vba, excel

In excel (and Excel VBA) it is really helpful to connect text and variable using "&":

```
a = 5
msgbox "The value is: " & a
```

will give

```
"The value is: 5"
```

How can I do this in R? I know there is a way to use "[paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201341/how-can-2-strings-be-concatenated)". However I wonder if there isn't any trick to do it as simple as in Excel VBA.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `paste` is pretty simple, as well as `sprintf("The value is: %d", a)`

Comment: sorry, didn't see your comment before posting answer ...

Answer (score 5):

[This blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-handy-concatenation-operator/) suggests to define your own concatenation operator, which is similar to what VBA (and Javascript) has, but it retains the power of `paste`:

```
"%+%" <- function(...) paste0(..., sep = "")

"Concatenate hits " %+% "and this."
# [1] "Concatenate hits and this."
```

I am not a big fan of this solution though because it kind of obscures what `paste` does under the hood. For instance, is it intuitive to you that this would happen?

```
"Concatenate this string " %+% "with this vector: " %+% 1:3
# [1] "Concatenate this string with this vector: 1"
# [2] "Concatenate this string with this vector: 2"
# [3] "Concatenate this string with this vector: 3"
```

In Javascript for instance, this would give you `Concatenate this string with this vector: 1,2,3`, which is quite different. I cannot speak for Excel, but you should think about whether this solution is not more confusing to you than it is useful.

If you need Javascript-like solution, you can also try this:

```
"%+%" <- function(...) {
   dots = list(...)
   dots = rapply(dots, paste, collapse = ",")
   paste(dots, collapse = "")
}

"Concatenate this string " %+% "with this string."
# [1] "Concatenate this string with this string."

"Concatenate this string " %+% "with this vector: " %+% 1:3
# [1] "Concatenate this string with this vector: 1,2,3"
```

But I haven't tested extensively, so be on lookout for unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use `sprintf`:

```
a <- 5
cat(sprintf("The value is %d\n",a))
## The value is 5
```

the `%d` denotes integer formatting (`%f` would give "The value is 5.000000"). The `\n` denotes a newline at the end of the string.

`sprintf()` can be more convenient than `paste` or `paste0` when you want to put together a lot of pieces, e.g.

```
sprintf("The value of a is %f (95% CI: {%f,%f})",
        a_est,a_lwr,a_upr)
```