# Passing a variable in a solr auery

Tags: r, solr, solrcloud, solr-query-syntax, ropensci

I'm working with solr using r library solrium

After the connection to solr in the variable conn1, I make queries like this:

```html
solr_search(conn1,"collection_name", params = list(q = "price:1000",start = 0, rows = 20000,fl=c('column_name')))
```

But now, I want to perform a query using a variable:

```html
p = 1000000
d = solr_search(conn1,"collection_name", params = list(q = "price:p", start = 0, rows = 20000,fl=c('column_name' )))
```

And obviously it doesn't work. 
I have tried tricks that I found on Internet like 
"price":p
"price:${p}"
"price":{p}

But none of these worked.

Comment: While I'm not familiar with R or Solrium, it seems like [standard string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201341/how-can-two-strings-be-concatenated) is performed by using `paste("price:", p)`. This assumes that `p` is not user supplied - i.e. you can assume that the value is safe to send directly to Solr.

Comment: Oh wow it worked! Thank you 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not familiar with R or Solrium, it [seems like standard string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201341/how-can-two-strings-be-concatenated) is performed by using `paste("price:", p)`. This assumes that p is not user supplied - i.e. you can assume that the value is safe to send directly to Solr.