# How to print all the column names from a dataframe in Rstudio so that they are outputted as a single row or statement with plus sign

Tags: r, dataframe

I want the column names to show as:

"ID + Age + Name + ..... + Comments"

There are more than 30 columns and I can't seem to find a simple way to output them

Comment: Possible duplicate/Related : [How can two strings be concatenated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201341/how-can-two-strings-be-concatenated)

Answer (score 1):

Try `names` + `paste0`

```
paste0(names(df), collapse = " + ")
```